# How do I map an association through a model's parents if it can only belong to one of them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-associations

Let's say I have active records Measurable, Bag and ShoppingBag(which is basically a specific type of bag):

```
class Measurable < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :bag, class_name: Bag
    belongs_to :shopping_bag, class_name: ShoppingBag

end

class Bag  < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :shopping_bag, class_name: ShoppingBag

end

class ShoppingBag < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :bag, class_name: Bag

end
```

The Measurable can only belong to either a Bag or a ShoppingBag.

How can I setup the Measurable so that when I call

```
measurable.bag
```

it will get to the Bag it is associated with either directly, or via its ShoppingBag, without changing the relationship of the bags.

Comment: Unrelated, but Rails can infer the class name from the association, so you don't need to explicitly declare the class_name

Comment: I'm aware thanks Brent, just added it for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shopping bag is a specific bag, then you can declare it as a subclass.

```
class ShoppingBag < Bag
  // specific attributes
end
```

If you can't do that (as you suggest in your comment), then you can override the `bag` method of you measurable :

```
def bag
  super || shopping_bag.bag
end
```

Then you can add a mutual exclusion validation (not tested)

```
validates :bag, absence: true, if: :shopping_bag
validates :shopping_bag, absence: true, if: :bag
```

Comment: It's a little bit more complicated than that.  My example is just simplified.  I can't change the relationship of the bags.

Comment: @skepticscript I updated my answer accordingly, with another solution

Comment: I think the overridden bag method should be `super || shopping_bag.bag` here